# How to load textures after startup in XNA using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xna, textures

I've encountered a problem with my gameproject lately. When I load more than a certain number of textures (around 1000) at startup I recieve an error regarding memory (because I have to use 32-bit in XNA). I am self-taught and so have only basic knowledge of the "correct" ways to program a game. The project itself is getting very big and although I try to compress images together etc, I will have to use more than 1000 textures throughout the project.

**My question, then, is**: How can I load textures at other points in time than at startup in XNA, using vb.net? (I'm not using classes at all that I'm aware of, so I hope to stay away from that if possible)

Thank's for any feedback on this!
/Christian

Comment: Chances are high, that you won't actually need all 1000 textures at the same time. So unload them, whenever you don't need them. But preferably, start merging related textures into a single image (also known as a Spritesheet)

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Yes you are right, and that's exactly why I posted my question :) Which is: how do I load the textures at other points in time than at startup? (And how do I unload them if I need to do that?)

Comment: you can load textures any time, just make sure you load them only once. and when you don't need them just dispose them.

Comment: Aha! How to dispose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer seems a lot easier than I expected, if I'm doing it right at the moment(?).

I simply Load the content needed for all "Worlds" in the beginning of the game (in the Protected Overrides Sub LoadContent()) and then Dispose() and Load.Content() depending on what World is loaded later (in any Sub I choose):

```
TextureName = Content.Load(Of Texture2D)("")
TextureName.Dispose()
```

If there isn't any problem I'm not yet aware of, this seem to do the trick and does not leave me with the memory error in the start.

Thank you **Davor Mlinaric** and **Monset** for helping me along

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, so I'll just put my idea here. Declaration time: I am also self-taught developer, so the algorithm that I'm using isn't proven to be the standard or anything like that. Hope it helps!

I am using a single class called GContent witch is "instanciated" (more like loaded) the first thing when game starts. This class is static, and it has lists for all textures, sounds and spritefonts in game. So, anywhere in my code I can put `GContent.Texture("texture_folder\\texture_name");` (similar for sound and spritefont). Now, before this function loads `Texture2D`, it checks it's list of textures, and tries to return a texture with the name that is asked for in parameter. If it finds the right texture, it returns the texture from the list. If not, it uses `Content.Load(textureFullPath);` (by full path I don't mean "C:\Users\....") to load the texture, give it a name (`Texture2D.Name`) equal to the parameter `textureFullPath`, adds that texture to the list, and **then** returns the new texture. 
So, the more you play my game, the more textures will be loaded, if I don't load all the assets at the start of the game. Now, I imagine you can simply have an array of `string`s that represent all textures that are used by a single level, or a map, or main menu... This way, you could easaly create function that will take `List< string >` and try to load **or unload** all textures of one map/level/menu...
So, my answer is pretty much: have a static class with lists of assets and load/unload asset(s) from where ever in game you want!

Also, if my answer helped you, please, check it as an answer :)

Comment: Oh.. I can just use Content.Load("...") or Content.Unload("...") anywhere in the Update sub?